# How to use multiple Steam accounts without re-entering passwords?

Tags: steam

I'd like to switch between two Steam accounts (from the same windows user account) without having to re-enter their passwords. So basically I am trying to write a batchfile which takes care of the relevant files and/or registry settings, but for that I need to know

> Which files and registry settings change when logging in as another user?

Obvious bonus points for providing a batch file for that task.

Comment: Complete shot in the dark: Have you tried having 2 different steam installations?

Comment: @CruelCow No, though I don't think that would work without using two different windows accounts as well. Also it'd waste the space of multiple installations of games common between the steam accounts

Comment: Here you go. I realize this isn't a 100% complete answer, but there's really no way to string those together with just a batch file. As far as I know, you can't wait for the main Steam process to exit with a batch file, and Steam doesn't respond to kill signals either. You'd probably have to get your hands dirty with *shudder* PowerShell.

Comment: This has stopped working for me since the recent Steam UI updates. Very annoying.

Answer (score 16):

The Steam executable (`Steam.exe` on Windows) accepts a number of [command line parameters](http://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Command_Line_Options#Steam_.28Windows.29); you could try taking advantage of those.

Specifically, this one, which starts Steam and immediately attempts to log in with the given credentials:

> **-login %u %p**
>
> > This logs into Steam with the specified Username and Password combination. Replace %u with the username, and %p with the password you want to login with (Steam must be off for this to work).

And, since this doesn't work while Steam is running:

> **-shutdown**
>
> > This shuts down (exits) Steam.

Comment: thanks, that's a nice start. Though I was hoping for some file actions _before_ starting Steam such that it starts as if I logged in as that user the last time

Comment: If you have two different desktop shortcuts that have a different login %u and %p values you would be logging in as that profile. Technically those parameters are done [i]before[/i] steam starts so you would be logging in under different accounts. Of course you'd have to quit the current session of Steam if you are switching accounts.

Comment: @Sorean you're right of course. Actually I'm just hesitant to put my account passwords in clear text to a shortcut, maybe one of these files like `ClientRegistry.bob` or `ssfnSOMENUMBER` contains a less volatile way of access

Answer (score 2):

You can run TWO Steams with Sandboxie.
(Yeah, I know this is not what you want.
Still, this might worth a try if anyone is interested in such a solution.)