# 2 Steam Accounts W/ Different Games

Tags: steam

I have two steam accounts with different games and gameshare is not a thing for both of them, I'm wondering if there is a way to launch a certain steam game with a specific profile without having to login or out

Ex. open PUBG as 1 user
    open CSGO as another user

Comment: Related: [How to use multiple Steam accounts without re-entering passwords?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/32056/how-to-use-multiple-steam-accounts-without-re-entering-passwords?rq=1)

Answer (score 1):

You could have two instances of Steam installed; one logged into User A and the other logged into User B. As far as I know, you can't have a singular copy of Steam have two instances running on the same [computer] account, BUT two different computer accounts can use the same installed copy of Steam (basically run the Steam installer twice installing to different places).

All you have to do now is not use the `steam://run/appid/xxxxx` shortcuts, but instead use each specific instance's `"[Path to Steam with User A logged in]/steam.exe" --applaunch 730` and `"[Path to Steam with User B logged in]/steam.exe" --applaunch 578080`.

Comment: I am afraid it doesn't work like that, at least for me it doesn't work, farthest you get is to be able to log into steam (different steamusers)for both windows accounts (different windows accounts I use a multiseat program called aster v7 to make this happen) you cant play the same or different games though (both steam user accounts having separate licenses bought for each account for each game) if one account launches a game the other cant launch the same or any other game .. Sometimes the 2nd windows account user isnt able to log into steam to begin with (with separate steamusername etc)